# Is it possible to have an ethereum node that only listens for events?

Tags: events, nodes

Scenario:

A DApp requires specific events from ethereum or a sidechain,
DApp does not afford any miss or delay. There is no reliable
public RPC, so DApp developers decided to run a node.

Question:

Is there any solution to have a custom node that only
fetches the events and do not do anything else? (such as transaction
verification or storing non-required data).

Is it theoretically possible?

Is there any node implementation that could be configured to function this way?

Comment: There is an API-based solution provided by Moralis called Streams API that can help you with listing just events in real-time. I think this can help you with your use case. You don't have to maintain an RPC for this, you will only need a server to listen to the webhooks. If you are interested I can share more details in answer.

Comment: This is a common issue and the best practice (at least in my experience) is to be constantly fetching events from a few different providers like Chainstack, Infura etc + you may want to add in there eg Etherscan and Streams (like @JohnVersus suggests). This will help keep your mind at peace. Running your own node will just add to the stack of issues (in my experience), so I wouldn't go that route.